# Node.js + Socket.io: Connections leak memory when disconnected

Tags: node.js, heroku, memory-leaks, socket.io

Bit of back story:

My Node app, called Sleepychat (in production, hosted on Heroku) recently started reporting Memory Limit Reached errors (at 512MB). Luckily, Heroku allows this and won't crash the app until 5 times is reached, so that's good. However, I find it strange that this occurred only just after a recent push to Heroku which involved nothing more than adding a page. My theory was that Heroku might have used a newer version of Node on the update, but it seems that isn't the case. I downgraded and the error still occurs.

My source can be found on [GitHub](http://github.com/MrMeapify/sleepychat/blob/master/app.js). Line 185 is the connection code, and line 1553 is the disconnect code.

Now, I've had some time to run through the code using New Relic and Node Inspector to profile it, and it seems that any connection, whether allowed or immediately refused and disconnected, allocates a small amount of memory which isn't released upon disconnection.

For example, I navigate to localhost, the page connects on document ready, and New Relic shows a slight increase in memory. Usually about 500kb (which still seems large to me, but I'm guessing that's mostly the socket object). When I disconnect, no change occurs in New Relic. What's more interesting, is that I can spam page refreshes to rapidly spike memory usage. Earlier I mentioned that it doesn't matter whether or not the connection is refused. By this, I meant that after 3 connections within 15 seconds of each other, the site will immediately refuse new connections and disconnect.

Despite this, page refreshes (which automatically connect) increases RAM. I've looked through many times to see if I'm not releasing something, but to my knowledge, everything should be managed by the scope, so I have no idea what's leaking.

I've noticed some odd behavior once I added New Relic, though. Firstly, once Sleepychat hits its limit of 512MB, Heroku will report a Memory Limit Reached error, but New Relic will display as if a large chunk (~100MB) has been released. Despite that display, Heroku would later report an even higher usage on its next error. Secondly, New Relic reports a drop in memory usage whenever I use Node Inspector to record heap allocations, but goes right back up once I stop the recording.

Here's a snapshot file from Node Inspector (Actually an allocation timeline). 10 seconds in is when I start spamming page refreshes. Additionally, here's an image of what New Relic reports.

Snapshot: [Snapshot File](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3556q7bec856cal/20150808T134745.heapsnapshot)

New Relic:
[image]

I have no idea what's going on. Anyone have any ideas?